# Photorec not letting me recover files, prompting me with [process completed], why is it not detecting my SD card?

Tags: sd-card, macos-monterey, photorec

[image]

I am running MacOS Monterey version 12.0.1

Comment: Do you have a Mechanical or Solid State drive installed in the system. File recovery is absolutely not guaranteed. File recovery is based on being able to find all the fragments of a file in order to restore it.

Comment: It looks like I have a APPLE SSD AP1024R. What should my next step be?

Comment: You're confusing things. Photorec did not start at all. It failed with *Bad CPU type in executable*. Do you perhaps have a Mac with M1 processor?

Comment: Bad CPU is usually that you have a 32-bit version not 64. You also need to run it with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

"Bad CPU type in executable" should tell you something.

Looks like you have downloaded a version of the program that is not for your computer CPU architecture.

Is your Mac M1-based? or Intel-based? MacOS 12.0.1 would not run on the (respectably old) PowerPC-based Macs, so they are out of question.

As far as I can tell, PhotoRec has no official binary package for MacOS ono M1 CPU and in order to use the program, you have to compile it yourself.

Comment: macOS binaries - https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Comment: This is where I looked first. No M1 binaries, only Intel and PowerPC. On the other hand, "brew install" is supposed to work.

Comment: We don't know what architecture the OP has. AP1024R has been in use for several years. TBH, that they are trying to launch something from var/root doesn't give me much confidence they should be using commandline tools at all. I'd recommend Disk Drill instead.